# ActiveRecord validates inclusion in list - list isn't updated after new associated model created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a `Company` model and an `Employer` model. `Employer` `belongs_to :company` and `Company` `has_many :employers`. Within my `Employer` model I have the following validation:

```
validates :company_id, inclusion: {in: Company.pluck(:id).prepend(nil)}
```

I'm running into a problem where the above validation fails. Here is an example setup in a controller action that will cause the validation to fail:

```
company = Company.new(company_params)
# company_params contains nested attributes for employers

company.employers.each do |employer|
  employer.password = SecureRandom.hex
end

company.employers.first.role = 'Admin' if client.employers.count == 1

company.save!
admin = company.employers.where(role: 'Admin').order(created_at: :asc).last

admin.update(some_attr: 'some_val')
```

On the last line in the example code snippet, `admin.update` will fail because the validation is checking to see if `company_id` is included in the list, which it is not, since the list was generated before `company` was saved.

<s>Obviously there are ways around this such as grabbing the value of `company.id` and then using it to define `admin` later, but that seems like a roundabout solution.</s> What I'd like to know is if there is a better way to solve this problem.

**Update**

Apparently the possible workaround I suggested doesn't even work.

```
new_company = Company.find(company.id)
admin = new_company.employers.where(role: 'Admin').order(created_at: :asc).last
admin.update
# Fails validation as before
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but there is an issue in this part of the code:

```
validates :company_id, inclusion: {in: Company.pluck(:id).prepend(nil)}
```

The validation is configured on the class-level, so it won't work well with updates on that model (won't be re-evaluated on subsequent validations).

The docs state that you can use a block for inclusion in, so you could try to do that as well:

```
validates :company_id, inclusion: {in: proc { Company.pluck(:id).prepend(nil) }}
```

Some people would recommend that you not even do this validation, but instead, have a database constraint on that column.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. When I call `new_company.save` or `new_company.update(params)` I get `Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`. I just disabled the validation for now. Seems to create more problems than it solves.

Comment: when you get errors, always add the complete stack-trace!

Comment: @DanielBonnell I had the same error and later found the solution. I updated the answer with the correction, which is a proc instead of a lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing the inclusion validator here. If you want to validate that an associated model exists, instead of its id column having a value, you can do this in two ways. In ActivRecord, you can use a [presence validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence).

```
validates :company, presence: true
```

You should also use a [foreign key constraint](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key) on the database level. This prevents a model from being saved if there is no corresponding record in the associated table.

add_foreign_key :employers, :companies

If it gets past ActiveRecord, the database will throw an error if there is no company record with the given `company_id`.